# Editing feature attribute in layer, which is made from featureCollection, using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I know ArgGIS has a JS API to edit attributes of a layer when the layer is published as a feature service but is there a way to edit attribute values if a layer is made from geoJSON as a featureCollection?

Answer (score 1):

as per the documentation, it **is** possible to make edits to featureCollection features, but:

> "Edits are applied on the client not posted to the server."

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was reading this page https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_feature_layers.html and it is saying that "You can only perform editing on feature layers that reference a feature service". But I guess it won't really simplify my problem, because I would need to pass it back to server somehow.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to make a copy of a layer from a featureCollection, allow a user to edit that copy and save it back to the server (still as a copy).